# What is the name of the texture pack featured in "20 Things You Didn't Know About Minecraft"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saw a video by marosells, "[20 Things You Didn't Know About Minecraft](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T07AwQeF0Ws)", and I've been looking for the name of the texture pack used in it since then: it's like the regular texture pack, but way improved.

What is the name of the texture pack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [Faithful 32x32 pack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/72747-faithful-32x32-pack-updatemods-132/) by Vattic, which, as its name implies, is an attempt at a "faithful" higher-resolution recreation of the default texture pack.

Comment: I've used it and I prefer it to many of the fancier texture packs.